# How does linux detect a process which is hogging the CPU and should be removed rather than preempting?

Tags: worker, watchdog, preemption

In a work queue, if a function is hogging the system(eg. running an infinite loop), how will the kernel know that it is hogging and it has to either preempt or cancel the work?

Comment: *Every* thread gets preempted at the end of it's timeslice

Comment: but what if there is an infinte loop, will it preempt it forever?

Comment: In general, yes. Note that there are a number of programs (e.g. basically all GUI programs) whose "normal running" is indistinguishable from "infinite loop", right up until the point where they end. Each thread that is runnable (disregarding priority) will get *some* timeslices, that's the *point* of a scheduler